# how to run aws xray in ecs as a daemon which all other containers can sent data to

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-xray

In the link provided for [ECS AWS X-Ray implementation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/xray/latest/devguide/xray-daemon-ecs.html) it shows how to run xray as a sidecar to the application. so every application would have it how X-Ray. Is it possible to deploy xray as daemon so that only on instance of xray is there per EC2 all the application containers send to their xray daemon in the EC2 instance? can someone provide the task definition of how to set that up?

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify, Yes it is possible. You can take what is on the link you have given and turn that into a service. Since you are not using Fargate, you can use the [Daemon service type](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ecs_services.html#service_scheduler). This will put a service on each EC2 Instance that matches your task placement task placement constraints. Then you can use this Daemon Service to send your data to.

example task definition

```
{
  "family": "your-task-definition",
  "networkMode": "bridge",
  "containerDefinitions": [
    {
      "name": "xray-daemon",
      "image": "amazon/aws-xray-daemon",
      "cpu": 32,
      "memoryReservation": 256,
      "essential": true,
      "portMappings": [
        {
          "hostPort": 0,
          "containerPort": 2000,
          "protocol": "udp"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

When creating the Service just make sure to check the Service Type to Daemon.

Please note this will not work with Fargate as Daemons are not supported and you will have to use a side-car for each service.

Answer (score -1):

The AWS X-Ray Daemon can run as a side container alongside your application in ECS cluster. And I guess that you're planning to run a daemon in an ECS cluster that all containers can access and send data to. Currently there is similar [issue](https://github.com/aws/aws-xray-daemon/issues/53) on our Github and hope this helps.